# no callback to onOptionsMenuClosed(). and getting error in overriding onPanelClosed() functions

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have a fragment which is made using PreferenceFragment ,where I am overriding onOptionsMenuClosed(). But , its the callback is not coming to it.Neither is the call back coming to OnMenuOpened(), OnPanelCosed()...

This is what i have alredy tired.

```
@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Log.e(TAG, "close optionmenu");
   super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);
}
```

and for onPanelClosed this is what i am trying.

```
@Override
public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    Log.e(TAG,"on panel closed the feature id is vivek "+featureId);
    super.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu);
}
```

and when i do that for onPanelClosed(),
Please help me out with this..

Please suggest where i am getting it wrong. and is tere any other way to catch if menu is closed without selecting any option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i finally found a solution for this :)..
this is what is did.

```
public boolean isOverflowMenuOpen  = false;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    activity.getActionBar().addOnMenuVisibilityListener(new OnMenuVisibilityListener() {
    @Override
        public void onMenuVisibilityChanged(boolean isVisible) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            isOverflowMenuOpen = isOverflowMenuOpen ? false : true;
        }
    });
```

now from the variable isOverflowMenuOpen  i can track if the overflow menu is open or not.

Comment: Very helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: happy to help @dazed