# Click listener of overflow menu, android?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

What is the listener for click event of overflow icon in action bar?

It is not detected in the onoptions selected so where else it can be detected

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Log.e("id  ", ""+id);

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: What your Activity extends?

Comment: Actionbaractivity. I need the click listener of the overflow icon.

Comment: [Please see if this helps,,its an work around to let u know whenever overflow menu is opned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25117047/3382236)

Answer (score 1):

There is no onClick Listener for the overflow menu itself; only for items inside the menu. When you click on an element inside the overflow menu, onOptionsItemSelected() is called.

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        if(featureId == AppCompatDelegate.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR && menu != null){
            //overflow menu clicked, put code here...
        }
        return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu);
    }